# How to use \abovetopsep (to add space between a table's caption and tabular part)?

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, booktabs

I read in the documentation of the [booktabs package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/booktabs.html) that `\abovetopsep` can be used to add some space between a table and its caption (instead of the lower-level `\vspace{}`). However, the exact placement of that option is not clear (at least to me). Is it standalone? Is it an attribute of toprule?

After a few attempts, all failing with "Missing number, treated as zero" it's clear I don't know where to put it. I'm not going to list them as they are obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\abovetopsep` is a length macro. Use [`\setlength`](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-88.html) to modify it, place that in your preamble. For example:

```
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{1ex}
```

This space would be added above the line made with `\toprule`. If you specify the length in your preamble, no change within a table environment is required. Jut put the caption above, the space by `\abovetopsep` will follow automatically, then comes the toprule. A `\midrule`, also if placed at the top, would ignore this space.

Comment: That was fast! Thanks, Stefan, it works perfectly.

Comment: Isn't `\setlength` just a macro wrapper for assignment syntax?

I.e. isn't `\setlength{\abovetopsep}{1ex}` equal, in behaviour, to `\abovetopsep=1ex` ?

Comment: @Giel: that's true. `\setlength` is simply defined: `\def\setlength#1#2{#1#2\relax}`. The questioner was probably not aware how to use it as a length in general.